"How do I get data from a table with an ID in BeautifulSoup?
I am trying to get data from the table with id='stats_standard' using the BeautifulSoup and requests libraries, but I have tried various methods like using find and select, and I still receive None or []. Does anyone have a solution?
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/2023-2024/stats/2023-2024-Premier-League-Stats' 

page = requests.get(url) 

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')  

table = soup.find('table', id='stats_standard')
print(table) # None

i want to get data from the table

You need to account for JavaScript on that page. You may find selenium useful

At least one of the tables on that page is reliant on JavaScript for its dynamic construction.
BeautifulSoup in your code is parseing the document with no consideration for what JavaScript might be doing.
You could use selenium for this.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions

URL = "https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/2023-2024/stats/2023-2024-Premier-League-Stats"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    options = ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless=new")
    with webdriver.Chrome(options) as driver:
        driver.get(URL)
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
        selector = (By.ID, "stats_standard")
        table = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(selector))


The table you wish to scrape from that webpage is within comments, which is why BeautifulSoup can't find it. Remove the comment signs, then try parsing the table, and you should succeed.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/2023-2024/stats/2023-2024-Premier-League-Stats' 

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

res = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text.replace("<!--","").replace("-->",""),"html.parser")
print(soup.select_one("table[id='stats_standard']"))


SIM has the correct solution, but just to note, you can also let pandas parse the table. It uses beautifulsoup under the hood:
import pandas as pd
import requests


url = 'https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/2023-2024/stats/2023-2024-Premier-League-Stats' 
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

res = requests.get(url,headers=headers).text.replace("<!--","").replace("-->","")
df = pd.read_html(res, header=1, attrs={'id':'stats_standard'})[0]

print(df)

Output:
      Rk               Player   Nation    Pos  ... xG+xAG npxG.1 npxG+xAG.1  Matches
0      1           Max Aarons  eng ENG     DF  ...   0.06   0.00       0.06  Matches
1      2    Joshua Acheampong  eng ENG     DF  ...   0.00   0.00       0.00  Matches
2      3   Bénie Adama Traore   ci CIV  FW,MF  ...   0.19   0.06       0.19  Matches
3      4          Tyler Adams   us USA     MF  ...   0.06   0.00       0.06  Matches
4      5     Tosin Adarabioyo  eng ENG     DF  ...   0.05   0.04       0.05  Matches
..   ...                  ...      ...    ...  ...    ...    ...        ...      ...
598  576       Nicolò Zaniolo   it ITA  FW,MF  ...   0.39   0.28       0.39  Matches
599  577        Anass Zaroury   ma MAR  FW,MF  ...   0.12   0.10       0.12  Matches
600  578  Oleksandr Zinchenko   ua UKR     DF  ...   0.16   0.03       0.16  Matches
601  579           Kurt Zouma   fr FRA     DF  ...   0.06   0.06       0.06  Matches
602  580      Martin Ødegaard   no NOR     MF  ...   0.50   0.17       0.45  Matches

[603 rows x 37 columns]

